# How can I get the following Word template in Latex? Or settle for a similar SDE resume Latex template?

Tags: cv

I am applying to software development positions, and I found this great resume template on CareerCup.com:

http://www.careercup.com/resume

Unfortunately, it is in Microsoft Word, and I prefer the level of control offered by Latex. Can I find this template in Latex?

Or, I can settle for a very similar one, optimized for early career SDE industry positions.

Any resource suggestions/links are also appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! LaTeX doesn't use 'templates' in the way Word does. I think you will be lucky to find anything quite as specific as 'a very similar one, optimized for early career SDE industry positions'. You could trying converting the template but it may be better to find a CV package which supports a style you like and then adapt it to meet your specific requirements. There are templates around for using such packages. `moderncv` seems to be a popular package but see http://ctan.org/topic/cv for a range of options.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the info. I have tried `moderncv`, but I am looking for a resume template, not a cv template. Particularly, I need my information to be very concise and on one page. I am currently using the `res` class, which is outdated and not flexible for maximizing space usage. I think I may try the `resume.cls` [here](http://people.debian.org/~dburrows/resume-cls.html)

Comment: Perhaps you should explain that in your question. I assumed that you meant a CV and am not aware of the terms being used to mark that distinction. (And neither, it seems is OED. It defines 'résumé' as a mostly North American term for a CV.) There are résumé packages on the page I linked though I don't know if they are using the term in your sense or not.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a template (for a résumé, CV, or otherwise) that makes a LaTeX document look like it was done in Word, so you'll probably have to write it from scratch. `\usepackage{wordlike}` might be a good place to start, though.

Comment: The linked example would be very easy to mimic using any standard or enriched (KOMA, memoir) documentclass,  All you really need are lines, lists, bold, and a way to evenly space out three bits of text on a line.  The only packages I would load to mimic that layout are font-related and `enumitem`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great resume template for SDE roles here:

http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2008/10/latex-resume-examples/

Rolling my own would be great, but it is much more convenient to work off an existing template and modify it as needed. Thank you for the advice!